# PHP MySQL trying to get multidemsional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have two tables, 1 with provinces and each province has an id. I have another table with cities and each city has province id with it. What I am trying to do is write query that will return a multidimensional array of each province with an array of cities that belong to that province.

```
example: Array(['Ontario'] Array('city1', 'city2'), ['Alberta'] Array('city3', 'city4'))
```

I wrote this query that gets my the city name and the province name that associated with the city name:

```
SELECT * FROM `cities` INNER JOIN `provinces` ON `cities`.`cityId` = `provinces`.`provinceId`
```

But I dont know what I have to do next to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this, would be to loop through the mysql-result and add every item to the array, like this:

```
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `cities` INNER JOIN `provinces` ON `cities`.`cityId` = `provinces`.`provinceId`");
while ($row = $res->fetch_array())
    $cities[$row["provinceName"]][] = $row["cityName"];
```